# Python Maze Game trouble

Tags: python, maze

I'm trying to make a game where you go through a maze and try to escape from a voice, but everytime the player says the wrong answer to one of the questions it says "Game Over" but then carries on where it kept off, I've tried a lot of things and researched, but I can't seem to figure it out, I'm only a beginner

`

import time
import os

```
    print ("Your adventure starts as a young boy, running away from home becuase you're a rebel")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You find the famous labyrinth, do you go in?")
    time.sleep(2)
    answer = input("Make your choice, Yes OR No")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("The answer",answer ,"got you stuck in a hole")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("But you find a secret passage")
    answer = input("Do you go through the door, Yes or No?")
    if answer == "No":
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("Game Over.")
    elif answer == "Yes":
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You hear a strange voice")
        time.sleep(2)
    answer = input("What do you say to the Voice, Hello or Who are you?")
    if answer == "Hello":
        print ("Hello")
    elif answer == "Who are you?":
        print ("Im your worst nightmare")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You try and escape the labyrinth and turn a large gate with a gnome on the over end")
    answer = input("Do you open the gate, Yes Or No?")
    if answer == "Yes":
        time.sleep(3)
        print ("Game Over, you get brutally killed by a gnome, good job")
        os._exit(0)
    elif answer == "No":
        time.sleep(3)
        print ("You go the other way and see a light at the end of the tunnel")
    answer = input("You see your family outside crying and waiting for you, do you go with them?")
    if answer == "Yes":
        print("You have a nice ending and you're sorry you ran away")
        print("You have been graded: ")
    elif answer == "No":
        print("God smites you for being stupid.")

        os._exit(0)`
```

Comment: Sorry if the code is too messy, hopefully you have the time to read it.

Comment: You could use some work on organization. Use whitespace (excessively if needed).

Comment: Totally agree dude, was in a rush to do this, dont have much time, just a hobby lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take this block, for example

```
print ("But you find a secret passage")
answer = input("Do you go through the door, Yes or No?")
if answer == "No":
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("Game Over.")
elif answer == "Yes":
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You hear a strange voice")
    time.sleep(2)
# continuation
```

if the user enters "No" it will print "Game Over" - which I assume is correct. However, control flow in the program continues past the `if/else` block. What you need to do is exit the program using something like `sys.exit()` or make sure your control flow only has paths forward if it should i.e. wrapping what happens next in the truthy part of the `if/else` block

```
if answer == "No":
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("Game Over.")
elif answer == "Yes":
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You hear a strange voice")
    time.sleep(2)

    # put continuation here
```

Comment: Or alternatively, add a `return` statement after `print ("Game Over.")` ;)